# CodeIgniter, Active Record or Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I got little confuse for Active Record(AR) in CI, since I compare it in Ruby On Rails, according to Rails guide, Active Record means

> the layer of the system responsible for representing business data and logic. Active Record facilitates the creation and use of **business objects whose data requires persistent storage to a database**. It is an implementation of the Active Record pattern which itself is a description of an Object Relational Mapping system.

For example of AR in CI

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

it looks more like query builder than AR, please some explain since I just start use CI just few weeks ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Codeigniter Active record**

CodeIgniter uses a modified version of the Active Record Database Pattern. This pattern allows information to be retrieved, inserted, and updated in your database with minimal scripting. In some cases only one or two lines of code are necessary to perform a database action. CodeIgniter does not require that each database table be its own class file. It instead provides a more simplified interface.

[Refer this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Changelog version 3.0.0: (March 30, 2015)

> Renamed the Active Record class to Query Builder to remove confusion with the Active Record design pattern.

Comment: Awesome, I should read user guide more detail, thanks for your time sir

Answer (score 0):

About Active record in Codeigniter is on Wikipedia:

*CodeIgniter has a query builder it calls "ActiveRecord", but which does not implement the Active Record pattern. Instead, it implements what the user guide refers to as a modified version of the pattern. The Active Record functionality in CodeIgniter can be achieved by using either CodeIgniter DataMapper library or CodeIgniter Gas ORM library.*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern